# loadNibFile - nib file not loaded

Tags: objective-c, mono, monobjc

Is there a way to query why a nib file could not load? The result is simply YES or NO: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBundle_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html.

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reason why a NIB could not be loaded (bad connections between instances and outlets, file not found, etc).

Running the application on the command-line (via the Terminal application) can show you some warning/error logs and help you diagnose the problem.

If your application is namd `CocoaApp` and located under your `Desktop` folder, then the commands to type into the Terminal application will be:

```
$> cd Desktop
$> ./CocoaApp.app/Contents/MacOS/CocoaApp
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the response. I was hoping to find something I could call within code to find out. Also, I am using C# with mobjc bridge and not directly using objective-c. I did try running the app in the command line doing mono mobjcMono.exe but received the same error: couldn't load the nib file at "directory".

Comment: Are you putting your application in a bundle or do you have the main assembly and nib in the same folder ? In order for the nib to be found, you have to respect a certain file structure.